# jrebel exclude file ( messages.properties )

Tags: java, jrebel

At first, sorry for my bad English

I want set exclude files in jrebel for example all of properties files ( *.properties ) in jrebel ( Java jRebel )

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ant-like include/exclude directives in rebel.xml configuration:

[see the docs for details](http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel-reference-manual/app.html#app-include)

Comment: in that case, the best would be to ask at the support forum http://zeroturnaround.com/forum/